# Xcode trouble with constraints for buttons

Tags: objective-c, xcode, constraints, spacing

I am creating a painting/drawing app. I am trying to make everything fit in the view on a 3.5 inch device (so far I have created it to fit a 4 inch device). I have 35 buttons in one of my views for the user to choose the stroke color and size. I understand that the buttons will need to be resized. What is the best way to do this? Everything in the view was inserted through the interface builder. This is what I am working with (the whitespace at the top is an iAd banner):

https://drive.google.com/#folders/0BxjZ6v5AeGPpVktWNmQ5ZmZjQ28

I have been playing about with constraints for some time now but I cannot manage to get the buttons to resize. I feel I may have been close at some points but never completely successful. I was hoping for some help from someone who understands them a little better! So to clarify, I am simply trying to get everything to fit on the screen when the user is on a 3.5 inch device. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I used Autoresizing and it worked well. You need to play around with them a bit. If you explain what exactly your buttons are doing, maybe you will get clearer answers.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input! I'll have a play with autoresizing and let you know how it goes!